# Invalid identifier oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

This error seems to appear a lot and I've had mixed answers such as changing names, but I couldn't see any issues with my query regarding this. Perhaps I have not spotted something?

For example:

```
select
  sport,
  sum(turn_over) as turnover,
  count(distinct(user_no)) as users,
  sum(turn_over) / count(distinct(user_no)) as average,
  extract(
    month
    from
      ref_date
  ) as outer_month,
  extract(
    year
    from
      ref_date
  ) as outer_year
from
  dw_unica.T_DAILY_SB
group by
  sport,
  outer_month,
  outer_year;
```

Gives the following error:

```
ORA-00904: "OUTER_YEAR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 61 Column: 271
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a keyword and not a function; you do not need the brackets following the keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `GROUP BY` clause as the `SELECT` clause is processed after the `GROUP BY` clause.

You need to `GROUP BY` the underlying function calls rather than the aliases:

```sql
select sport,
       sum(turn_over) as turnover,
       count(distinct user_no) as users,
       sum(turn_over) / count(distinct user_no) as average,
       extract(month from ref_date) as outer_month,
       extract(year from ref_date) as outer_year
from   dw_unica.T_DAILY_SB
group by
       sport,
       extract(month from ref_date),
       extract(year from ref_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do Group By outer_year whicch does not exist (it is an alias). The same stands for outher_month.

```sql
Group By
  sport,
  extract(month from ref_date),
  extract(year from ref_date)
```